# Where to go to get objective brand recommendatons?

Tags: support

I understand that requests for brand recommendations is forbidden on this site.

Are there websites that have independent, objective evaluations of the type of building supplies typically found in hardware stores, paint shops, and lumber yards?

Comment: Amazon is the world's best collection of "independent" reviews, in my opinion. Most of what you find at those stores is also there. Otherwise, a web search with "reviews" appended usually yields something useful.

Comment: Asking where to go to get product recommendations is a product recommendation itself. VTC as off-topic. Amazon or google are your friends, as are the websites of your hardware stores, paint shops, and lumber yards.

Comment: @mmathis  I use google reviews, but google reviews are usually posted shortly after purchase, so typically do not evaluate durability.